# Distribution of infinite nested radicals with random terms

Tags: random-variables, nested-radicals, cantor-set

Let's say we have an infinite nested radical with random terms (positive integers) which can take on finitely many values in the range $(n_1,n_2)$. What would the  distribution look like for these radicals if all terms appear with equal probability?

I naively expected it to look, well, random, even for $n_2=n_1+1$. However, this is not the case.

See how the distribution looks for infinite radicals with random terms which can be either $1$ or $2$ (number of terms is $300$ in each radical, size of the distribution is $700$, the histogram contains $250$ bins, and I used Mathematica RandomInteger):

[image]

It's obvious, that the numbers can't be smaller than the golden ratio:

$$\phi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}=1.618034$$

And can't be larger than $2$:

$$2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}$$

There are also two more 'attractors' for this distribution:

$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}}=1.710644$$

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=1.926303$$

> What I can't explain is the occurence of 'doublets' for each spectral line (which appear in any experiment I've run, for other pairs of numbers as well).
>
> And how to find the size of the 'line broadening'? What does it depend on?

This is what the distribution looks like for terms which can take values $1,2,3$:

[image]

---

See also the thesis about nested radicals and Cantor sets [here](http://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2149&context=theses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write your nested radical as $r(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = \sqrt{x_1 + \sqrt{x_2 + \sqrt{x_3 + \ldots}}}$. 
Thus

$$r(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = \sqrt{x_1 + r(x_2, x_3, \ldots)}$$

In particular, since $r$ is an increasing function of each $r_i$,
if the possible values are $1$ and $2$

$$\sqrt{r_1 + \phi} \le r(x_1, x_2, \ldots) \le \sqrt{r_1 + 2}$$

so that the distribution will be supported in the union of intervals
$$[\sqrt{1+\phi},\sqrt{3}] \cup [\sqrt{2+\phi}, 2] \approx [1.618033988, 1.732050808] \cup [1.902113032, 2]$$

If you take the two possible values of $r_2$ into account,each of these intervals splits into two, and this continues; the end result is a somewhat distorted image of the Cantor set.

Similarly for your next example, but splitting each interval into three instead of two.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you. So, if the size of the distribution becomes infinite, do I get an infinite number of 'infinitely thin' lines? The Cantor set has measure $0$, will this be the case for this distribution also? For any finite number of term values?

Comment: If we use numbers 2 to 6, the intervals unite and cover the whole region. Thanks for the method, it's very useful

Comment: To avoid gaps, see my solution at https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/math-fun-infinite-nested-radicals-of-random-variables